# TypeScript 3 parameter list intersection type

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/07/30/announcing-typescript-3-0/#tuples-and-parameters) improved parameter lists.

I'm looking at the type definiton for `Object.assign`, it looks something like this:

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
    assign<T, U, V>(target: T, source1: U, source2: V): T & U & V;
    assign<T, U, V, W>(target: T, source1: U, source2: V, source3: W): T & U & V & W;
    ...
```

I'm wondering if we can rewrite that method signature without overloads now? i.e. can we express that the return value is the intersection of all input arguments, or is this still not possible?

I need something very similar for a function I'm working on.

Answer (score 13):

While I like @y2bd's answer, I think it will have a problem if any of the passed-in parameters are themselves union types:

```
const eitherOr = Math.random() < 0.5 ? { c: "4" } : { c: 5 };
const notSoGood = assign({ a: "2" }, { b: "3" }, eitherOr);
notSoGood.c; // string & number ?!
```

You will find that `eitherOr` gets turned from a union to an intersection, and `notSoGood` is not the right type.

A way around that is to "box" and "unbox" the tuples so that you can distinguish single-parameters-which-are-unions from the union of multiple parameter types:

```
type BoxedTupleTypes<T extends any[]> =
  { [P in keyof T]: [T[P]] }[Exclude<keyof T, keyof any[]>]
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
type UnboxIntersection<T> = T extends { 0: infer U } ? U : never;
declare function assign<T, S extends any[]>(
  target: T,
  ...sources: S
): T & UnboxIntersection<UnionToIntersection<BoxedTupleTypes<S>>>
```

Now you'll have the right type:

```
 const notSoGood = assign({ a: "2" }, { b: "3" }, eitherOr);
 notSoGood.c // string | number
```

---

That being said I don't know if this version has its own problems.  Not to mention that intersection isn't really what you want anyway.  You'd rather [overwrite properties if possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316#issuecomment-359574388), which intersection doesn't capture.  So before we suggest changing the standard library we might want to think about the best signature that TypeScript has to offer us.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Is the way of writing the array type parameter in `assign<T, S extends any[]>` just a personal preference or is there an advantage over `assign<T, S>(target: T, ...sources: S[]): T & UnboxIntersection<UnionToIntersection<BoxedTupleTypes<S[]>>>`? Are these types the same?

Comment: There is a definite advantage.  You want to infer a tuple type, not just an array type. If `S extends T[]`, it does not mean that `S` *is* `T[]`.  If you only infer `T`, you've lost whether `S` came from a tuple type like `[string, number]` as opposed to an array type like `Array<string | number>`.  Which, for parameter lists, defeats [the purpose](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-rest-parameters) of doing the inference in TS3.0 and up.

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation. I see now there is a difference between a tuple type and array type.

Answer (score 12):

Let's start with converting a tuple of types to a union of types in the tuple:

```
type TupleTypes<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] } extends { [key: number]: infer V } ? V : never;
type A = TupleTypes<[1, "hello", true]>; // === 1 | "hello" | true
```

Then we borrow from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) to convert from a union of types to an intersection of types:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never;
type B = UnionToIntersection<A>; // === 1 & "hello" & true
```

Now that we have that, let's write a wrapper for `Object.assign`:

```
function assign<T extends object, S extends object[]>(target: T, ...sources: S): T & UnionToIntersection<TupleTypes<S>> {
    return Object.assign(target, ...sources);
}

const good = assign({ a: "2" }, { b: "3" }, { c: "4" }, { d: "4" }, { g: "5" });
// const good: { a: string; } & { b: string; } & { c: string; } & { d: string; } & { g: string; }
```

Comment: I wanted to comment on this but it became too long and hard to format the code, so I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51604379/2887218)