# Generate type as an array of elements typed sequentially based on another type's properties

Tags: typescript

Sorry for the confusing title, hopefully the code should make the question clear.

I have the `ExpenseItem` type and want to generate a finite array where the type of each element in the array corresponds to a property of `ExpenseItem`.

I've actually solved this already by writing out the types out manually (`ExpenseMatrixRow` below). It just seems wasteful that as I keep adding properties to `ExpenseItem` I also need to manually update `ExpenseMatrixRow`.

```
type ExpenseItem = {
  date: Date;
  title: string;
  value: number;
  category?: string;
};

type ExpenseMatrixRow = [
  {value: ExpenseItem['date']},
  {value: ExpenseItem['title']},
  {value: ExpenseItem['value']},
  {value: ExpenseItem['category']},
];

type ExpenseMatrix = ExpenseMatrixRow[];

const row : ExpenseMatrixRow = [
  {value: new Date()},
  {value: 'some title'},
  {value: 3},
  {value: 'some category'},
]

const matrix : ExpenseMatrix = [row, ...manyOtherRows]
```

(Updated code with better examples)

Comment: Should the items in the array come in that specific order?

Comment: Yes, order is important since the goal is to build a matrix (updated code with better examples).

Comment: Since the keys of an object are not ordered, any "automatic" solution would anyway require that you specify the order of the keys, at least in a list. So I think that the way you do it is the best you can get.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible since an object type doesn't define any order of elements, so TS can't know in what order the resulting array should be.

The only option that comes to my mind to stay DRY is to define some helper structure that contains all the required information (keys and order) and build both array and object types from that:

```
type ExpenseDefinition = [
    ['date', Date],
    ['title', string],
    ['value', number],
    ['category' | undefined, string],
]

// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32917#issuecomment-521653312
type TupleIndex<T extends unknown[]> = Exclude<
  Partial<T>["length"],
  undefined | T["length"]
>;
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/51604379/1660584
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

type ToMatrixRow<T extends [key: string | undefined, value: unknown][]> = {
    [Index in TupleIndex<T>]: {
        value: T[Index][1] | (undefined extends T[Index][0] ? undefined : never)
    }
}
type ToItemObject<
  T extends [key: string | undefined, value: unknown][]
> = UnionToIntersection<{
    [Index in TupleIndex<T>]: undefined extends T[Index][0]
        ? {
            [Key in Exclude<T[Index][0], undefined>]?: T[Index][1]
        }
        : {
            [Key in Exclude<T[Index][0], undefined>]: T[Index][1]
        }
}[TupleIndex<T>]>;

type ExpenseMatrixRow = ToMatrixRow<ExpenseDefinition>;
type ExpenseItem = ToItemObject<ExpenseDefinition>;
```

[live demo here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=52#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHpAdgZwgEQgMwJaO8bAe0SgF4oBtAWACgp7KByAEwENgJGAaKNdiALpdaDJgWAAbTj2TAATrgDmQkQwqMAbqwkBXaVEQ6AtgCMIclXTWMAxv0WE5IRlAA%20UHYmZZcEZjPklSwFaWgB6MKgAC2BgMGQALgjFfCidEwA6G0IjMKNsGzlCZEJMYDCAFXAIAGVC7DBy7GRkPWQwgGYAJgBOAEYAdgBiZtaIbKMjCERgAFoAVi6%20gDZ5jo6%20rtpQSCgKnTApAEkvCDgAHgqoM44vZA9EAGtEQgB3RAoBAD4yWDgbXTec4ABVYcgI2kuXwoACIpIhFMAojChA9vDhEH43HtYfDEcjvgBucKRGJxRIRWSsGyPQgacyYCRvLI5MKsMLzFYABgALB0Bj0witllz5gAOHnbapQACqeGIFUIJw4clQNgIxHOMp%20pFUAAoZdc4LdmPdWIgQFAAPxQPWPBKygCUZB%20GkI2GYUAdmPpcmdN2mpttdoduEw5igR2dpFd7uYzptRy9BggvuJNClu0VAFl2Ao4AAlN6XI0m%204UR4QEAO2QKBHYzzo3z%20KBaXQQB2eZ5vRACT46qAAb1U9AoJ28cCguD2B2OpwuFS%20Agdw6sonobb0DoqY-nfb6AmxesbPkxnoDdxx47Ofa5h5tJ4xWO9qfMjpHUAAvrRvzQdtBFSODgjAAeRMAArcZgBLC8gwrKsa0Cet3EfZseE3DsHm7d4%202%20X45SIRBAJmcw1Q1RBzlXURdwnKcSH2Q4IGvBcl07U4n3PY1A3uHdmNvEI13XG0qPXUSKAAaSrOi-gBHQgV4vcKDvHhULPJcrW3GibwoA8P1EX9RPoFc9MMiSpOneBZPkrS4H4lT2ObVir0U3TBP0n8KAYucJyhIlQj-aV4CQVBc0CQs3l%20HM82wcLXnOILplQDAMXwQivnTf8-mCpjgMipVgLAyD1XihBEvQU9UuIdKgA)

but it is quite a lot of magic for questionable benefit. I'd think in the first place what issue I'm trying to solve - to I really need the matrix typed? Or shouldn't the matrix be `ExpenseItem[]` rather that a two-dimensional array, which will definitely be more comfortable to work with? Or if you e.g. export to csv, can't you just drop the strict typing in the last step?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. For some reason your code allows `ExpenseMatrixRow` arrays of length > 4, with the element 4 and above being untyped. Very good point about dropping the row/matrix typing altogether, as I actually work with an object array and only convert it to matrix in the end due to a library requirement. TS seems to have no problem inferring things, so I'll just do that.

Comment: Just note - it is correct that you can assign an array of length > 4 to a tuple of length 4, since it conforms to the interface of the tuple, similarly like you can assign objects with extra properties to interfaces that needs only some of them.

Comment: I may be missing something but I can't see how either of those statements are true. If you use the tuple definition I provided in the question (`ExpenseMatrixRow` ), as soon as you add a 5th element tslint warns "Source has 5 element(s) but target allows only 4.(2322)". Similarly for an object the error is even more obvious: "Object literal may only specify known properties"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - you are true that tuple length must always match. For objects, typescript allows assignment of subtypes (objects with extra props), but not with assigning object literals - although `const a: {foo: number} = {foo:1, bar:1}` is correct by type theory, it is very likely a mistake, so typescript decided to report an error in such cases.

Comment: So now I probably see the problem - my technique to define `ExpenseMatrixRow` declares it as an object with attributes 0, 1, ..., and typescript treats it as an object rather than tuple, that's why it allows longer arrays (which are considered to be just extra properties). And I don't know if there is a way to build an actual tuple like this. But this is really a bleeding edge of typescript, as typescript is a compromise between theoretical correctness and usability and making such tricky types both correct and strict is always a pain.